# How to find a set of characters in a string

Tags: c++, string, find, substring

I am working on a project and I am facing a problem. I need to find a set of characters in a string like if user enters his/her email then i have to check whether the email is correct or not. I am finding it to use the string class `find` function but i haven't succeeded. I can use the loop to find the last character but I and looking for a simplest method to work for it.
Example: `email@gmail.com` I want to get `.com` as the last characters of string.

Here is the code of mine:

```
string checkEmail(const char* const prompt) {
    string str;
    bool check = true;
    do {
        cout << prompt << " : ";
        cin >> str;
        if (str.find_last_of(".com")) // here is the error, I think
            check = false;
    } while (check);
    return str;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code where you use the result of `str.find` to subset the string

Comment: I don't understand the question very well, do you want to check whether the input string ends with ".com", or do you want to get the last couple of characters from a string

Comment: @FatihBAKIR Yes, you're right. I want to find the the last 4 character of a string to check whether it is  `.com` or not.

Comment: @EdChum I'm sorry, I had changed the code but I have tried with `str.find` too. But no success! :(

Comment: If your goal is to check if a valid e-mail address was entered, that's [not so easy](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt). You're better off using an existing validator. If you don't need to be so strict, you can just check for the presence of an `@` and for a valid looking domain part (after the `@`). Usually, you also want to send a confirmation e-mail to it to make sure the address exists and is owned by the person that entered it.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker If i want to confirm that the email address is perfectly matched to a valid email address then what method I should choose for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to first get the last 4 characters as an `std::string`, then you can compare it with ".com":

```
std::string email = "example@mail.com";
std::string ext = email.substr(email.length() - 4, 4);
bool check = ext == ".com";
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if it was **not** found:

```
if (str.find_last_of(".com")==std::string::npos){
    check = false;
}
```

---

To check if it **was** found:

```
if (str.find_last_of(".com")!=std::string::npos){
    check = false;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, Are you sure that `x.com.yyy` would be a valid result?

Comment: @SergeBallesta That's why i am looking for such an solution that will check there is only and `.com` substring at the end is here or not?